# What DB Engine Version is my Aurora MySQL Setup using?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

The version selected, Aurora (MySQL)-5.7.12 is differently versioned than the others, which start with 2.03.2 and go to 2.08.2.

I want to be on the latest version. Which version am I running? And are there concerns with switching to the latest version?

(The light-blue entry is what I have apparently selected, when viewed through the AWS Console).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Aurora (MySQL)-5.7.12` is the oldest version you can "upgrade" to (in your case that's the version you're already running). The latest version is typically listed at the bottom of the selector list.

There's a [changelog of all Aurora MySQL versions since 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.20Updates.html).

The current version as of 2021-10-21 is `Aurora (MySQL 5.7) 2.10.1`.

Generally each Aurora MySQL release brings bug fixes and, occasionally, new features, which of course could introduce new bugs. However Amazon seems to be very conservative in making major changes, and in my experience upgrading to the latest version has always been beneficial to the companies I've worked for. Upgrades within the 2.0 series can be performed in place and do not require a backup-and-restore of the cluster.